# HTML: Menus as UL instead of DIVs?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I recently created a menu for a web page where buttons are DIV elements. I've been Googling around and see that many people create UL lists and each button is a LI element. What benefit is using an UL and LIs instead of just DIVs? Is it somehow better for SEO? Does this have to do with "semantic" markup? Any compelling reason to rewrite my menu as a UL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the more semantically correct approach. A menu can be regarded an unordered list ( `ul` ) and each item as a list item ( `li` ).

Excessive use of `div` elements is also known as "divitis" and should be avoided where possible. (Which, of course, doesn't mean that `div` elements are bad per se. There are legitimate use cases for `div` s in almost every web page.)

There is no functional difference in using more semantically sound elements but it makes for better, easier to read code, and enables you to build CSS definitions with less overhead.

Compare for example

```
div.menu { ..... }
div.menu div.subitem { ..... }
div.menu div.level2 div.subitem { ..... }
```

to

```
ul { ..... }
ul li { ..... }
ul ul li { ..... }
```

Prominent examples of where `div`s could be replaced by more fitting elements:

- As already said, Menus: `<ul><li>`
- Forms with labels:  `<fieldset><label>`
- Headings  `<h1><h2>` (just the headings, not complete header areas though)

Comment: +1 The menu would be in a div, with the components in the menu being in the form of a list. This is a valid approach.

Comment: @Pekka: +1: That's a better explanation than what i said :)

Comment: Yep, I love lists. You usually get better results styling the CONTENTS of the list rather than the lists themselves. i.e. - style the A tag in the list, not the LI.

Comment: I'll get this out of the way -- I'm pro lists for nav items. Just being the devil's advocate. Your comparison ought to actually have the lists be ul.menu, ul.menu li.subitem, ul.menu ul.level2 li.subitem for fair comparison. In that sense you're only dropping a single character from your CSS, so really is there that much less overhead in the CSS definition? And is the code that much easier to read?

Comment: @Gavin you're right that my example isn't 100% fair: it'll need at least one class name in the root: `ul.menu li li`... the child elements often don't need pointing out a class because their position in the structure will be enough to point them out.